# How to control how udev tags the input devices?

Tags: udev, input

I create virtual devices using uinput that are then properly detected by udev which seems to be assigning a tag like "mouse" or "tablet".

I guess udev does this by judging the capabilities set for the device: if I set EV_REL, udev seems to tag my device as a "mouse", which is good for me, but if I set EV_ABS, udev seems to decide it is a "tablet", which is probably perfectly correct but not what I need. Would it be possible to write some udev rule to ask udev to tag as "mouse" a device even though it has the capability EV_ABS?

The final result that I need is to create a virtual device using uinput, detected as "mouse" (not "tablet"), where I can set absolute coords instead of relative. Would it be possible to do this? Can I force this with a udev rule maybe?

Thanks!